# How should I set data from an asynchronous service into a controller $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

All server data accesses in my page are performed by my RequestFactory provider.
(The RequestFactory uses $http to perform the actual server calls.)

My controller scope has a reference to the list of data returned from the RequestFactory.

My question is that since the RequestFactory calls are asynchronous, and the RequestFactory does not (and should not) have access to the controller scope, what is the proper way for the RequestFactory to hand off the data to the controller?

```
var requestFactory = {};
angular.module("myApp").factory("RequestFactory", function($http) {
    requestFactory.fetch = function() {
        $http.get(url).
            success(function(data) {
                controller.setData(data)
            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                console.info("fetch Failed. Error code: " + status + " Url:" + url);
            }).finally(function() {
                controller.setSubmitting(false);
            });
    };
    return requestFactory;
});
```

Comment: You should return the promise from the factory to your controller and then access the data in your controller. :-)

Comment: @Vineet ahh, seems right, why not make it an answer and I will check it up, if you can provide a snippet of how to grab the promise

Comment: Okay can you please share your code ?

Comment: checkout my answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the promise from you factory. See below snippet.

```
.factory("RequestFactory", function($http) {
   return {
     fetch : function() {
        return $http.get(url).then(function(result) {
           return result.data;
        });
     }
   }
});
```

In your controller you should use like

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, RequestFactory) {
  RequestFactory.fetch().then(function(data) 
     $scope.foo = data;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($http){

    function get(){
      //We return a promise
      return $http.get('path_to_url');
    }

    var factory = {
      get: get
    };

    return factory;

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Request', Service);

})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, $q, Request) {

  var defer = $q.defer();

  //Call our get method from the Request Factory
  Request.get().then(function(response){
    //When we get the response, resolve the data
    defer.resolve(response.data);
  });

  //When the data is set, we can resolve the promise
  defer.promise.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

As you know, `$http` service return promise, so after that, you can easily combining them.